# How do we account for tipped transactions with Yodlee which are duplicated, with differing amounts?

Tags: transactions, yodlee, deduplication

We have a Yodlee integration and are experiencing an issue with double transactions posting.  Here's are the conditions with scenario:

1) It is a tipped situation where the credit card is run at an amount and then later on a tip is added so the card is run at a slightly higher amount.

2) happens with Comerica bank, haven't had any reports of any other.

So let's say there is transaction that covers the bill for dinner at a restaurant for $50.  After the card is brought back to the customer, they add $10 tip.

The client sees the first $50 transaction come through in a day or so as posted from yodel to our software.   A few days later they see another transaction for the same vendor that is for $60.    Both are now in our software.  Both represent the same visit to the restaurant.

How have people done implementations to account for this?  Is there a yodlee transaction status or ID or anything that can help us link these?

Answer (score 0):

There is a transaction status on the transactions that shows whether the transaction has been posted or is pending.

When a TXN moves from pending to posted it seems the pending txn is deleted on Yodlee's end, and a new posted txn is created with a different TransactionId.

For our purposes we delete txns out of our database on an update run if they are pending, and their id is not present in the transaction list we get back from Yodlee (given that the transaction should exist in the time period of the txn's we get from Yodlee).

This should work for you if the original $50 transaction is initially pending, and then post at $60.